# Delaying a PayPal payment for more than 90 days

Tags: paypal

So there I was, browsing the PayPal Adaptive Payments API and I encountered *Delayed Chained Payments*. Looks like exactly what I need to implement a booking system for camping vans: The majority of the payment is supposed to be delayed until ten days after the trip (which gives us some times to solve any grievances).

Yet this part of the API only allows to delay a payment for 90 days, which is not enough for my purpose: People tend to book campers for the summer during winter time, so 180 days is common.

Does anyone know another part of the Paypal API that allows delays that long? Or is there a way to hack this, maybe with some kind of recurring payment?

Answer (score 0):

I found no way to extend the 90 day period, even support did not know of a way. But since no one responded yet, I would like to point out my rather boring work-around:

Instead I used the [pre-approval process](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-basicPreapproval-curl-etc/), which allows payments to be subtracted from a user account for up to a year. You simply define a maximum amount of money to be subtracted.

Pros:

- Allows for a full year of delayed payments
- Allows multiple payments to be made in that timeframe
- No need for the first recipient to hold all the money (which might get you in trouble with some financial institutions)

Cons:

- Is limited to 2000 USD, but this limit can be waived by PayPal (unlike the 90 day limit - at least I was unsuccessful there).
- The approval can be cancelled by the user (though there is a small security-though-obscurity protection: Finding where to cancel this is hard)

Meh:

- Like delayed chained payments, pre-approved payments require permission from PayPal